# webclient.downloadfileasync fails to download full file

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to download a file using webclient.downloadfileasync ,but it downloads only 16 kb the full size of the file is about 500kb

This is my code :

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Module Module1
  Private WithEvents thttp As WebClient
    Sub main()
     Try
        thttp = New WebClient
        thttp.DownloadDataAsync(New Uri("URL"), IO.Path.GetTempPath &  "\app.exe")
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Try
            If System.IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.GetTempPath & "\app.exe") =  True Then
                MsgBox("Update Complete")
            Else
                MsgBox("Update Failed")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
  End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: thttp.downloadfileasync(New Uri("URL"), IO.Path.GetTempPath &  "\app.exe")